# How to manage multiple categories and entry url formats

Tags: categories, sections

I have a setup in Craft 2 like below:

```
Section: products
Url format: flowers/{productCategory.last.uri}/{slug}

Categories: 
cat1 = Bouquets
cat2 = Valentines days
Url format: flowers/{slug}
```

The problem headache arises when I want to get the entry URL within a category template. It always gets the last category of the entry due to the URL format. So once valentines day is added as a second category then a normal bouquet entry URL goes from this:

```
/flowers/bouquets/entry-slug
```

to

```
/flowers/valentines-day/entry-slug
```

I solved this partly by making my bouquet URL out of the URL path:

```
            {% for entry in entries %}
                {% set prodUrl = 'flowers/'~ seg2~ '/'~entry.slug %}
                 <a href="{{ baseUrl }}{{ prodUrl }}" >
```

However, the entry template now doesn't have the entry model.

How do other people solve this multiple categories for the same content type issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple possible solutions here:

**1. Rethink your url structure**
You could always remove the category segment from the url. Maybe create a field for the main category and then another field for all the categories, and use the main category field for your URL. Or you could fetch the first `productCategory` instead of the last one, so there's less chance of it changing. In my opinion you're going to have a lot of SEO issues if your url changes whenever you add a new `productCategory`, not to mention broken links and all sorts of other headaches.

**2. Do some fancy stuff with routes and entry queries**
I think technically you could set up a route like `flowers/{productCategory}/{slug}` and then in your template do an entry query for an entry with that slug. But probably better to think over #1 and find a cleaner solution.

Comment: No 2 is on the radar and yes it feels dirty :) Will revisit no 1